How to avoid --unsafe-paths with "git apply" outside a repository?
I'm trying to apply a patch generated using git diff from two similar trees. None of the two trees are in a git repo. It only works if I pass --unsafe-paths to git apply (the diffs can contain renamed files which GNU patch doesn't support):
$ mkdir ~/test
$ cd ~/test
$ mkdir old
$ echo old > old/file
$ mkdir new
$ echo new > new/file

$ git diff --no-index old new > test.diff
$ cat test.diff 

diff --git a/old/file b/new/file
index 3367afd..3e75765 100644
--- a/old/file
+++ b/new/file
@@ -1 +1 @@
-old
+new

$ git apply -p2 --verbose --check ../test.diff
Skipped patch 'file'.

$ git apply -p2 --directory=old --verbose --check test.diff
Skipped patch 'old/file'.

$ git apply -p2 --directory=$PWD/old --verbose --check test.diff
Skipped patch '/home/user/test/old/file'.

$ cd /tmp
$ git apply -p2 --directory=$HOME/test/old --verbose --check ~/test/test.diff
Checking patch /home/user/test/old/file...
error: invalid path '/home/user/test/old/file'

$ cd ~/test
$ git apply -p2 --directory=$HOME/test/old --verbose --check --unsafe-paths ~/test/test.diff
Skipped patch '/home/user/test/old/file'.

$ cd /tmp
$ git apply -p2 --directory=$HOME/test/old --verbose --check --unsafe-paths ~/test/test.diff
Checking patch /home/user/test/old/file...

In short, setting --directory, and even changing to a directory that is not a prefix of that directory before doing so, all result in "Skipped patch" or "invalid path" errors.
Only the last command, which passes --directory, is run from /tmp which is not a prefix of that directory, and uses --unsafe-paths, is enough to work.
How can I avoid --unsafe-paths and the risk of changing files outside the directory I want to patch ?
